# Detect click on input via the name attribute

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I am trying to detect when one of these inputs are clicked and do a simple display none on a div. Everything I have tried will not detect a click. I do not have control over the html.

```
<div class="sibling csf--button csf--active">
  <input type="radio" name="setting[open_btn_icon]" value="icon_a" data-depend-id="open_btn_icon">
</div>

<div class="sibling csf--button csf">
  <input type="radio" name="setting[open_btn_icon]" value="icon_b" data-depend-id="open_btn_icon">
</div>
```

This is the last thing of many I have tried.

```
document.querySelector('[name="setting[open_btn_icon]"]').addEventListener("click", function() {
  alert("Hello World!");
});
```

Right now all I am trying to do is detect the click. I can do the rest.

I have tried with jquery. I can do what I need when there is a class or id or a name whe nit not formatted as an array value.

Answer (score 1):

I think your issue is the use of the `querySelector` method, which will only return a single element:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector

Consider using the `querySelectorAll` method, which will give you a NodeList that can be iterated over using a "for / of" loop.

In the end, your code would look something like:

```
let nodeList = document.querySelectorAll('[name="setting[open_btn_icon]"]');

for (let node of nodeList){

    node.addEventListener('click', function(){
        alert('Hello World!');
    }

}
```

**Alternatively**

Consider applying a single listener to the parent DIV instead `<div class="sibling csf--button csf--active">`, then checking to see if the element being clicked is the one you need to react to. Depending on how many elements you actually need to react to, this could potentially help with performance.

Answer (score 0):

It should fix your issue

```js
let all = document.querySelectorAll('[name="setting[open_btn_icon]"]')
all.forEach(x=>x.addEventListener("click", function() {
  alert("Hello World!");
}))
```

```html
<div class="sibling csf--button csf--active">
  <input type="radio" name="setting[open_btn_icon]" value="icon_a" data-depend-id="open_btn_icon">
</div>

<div class="sibling csf--button csf">
  <input type="radio" name="setting[open_btn_icon]" value="icon_b" data-depend-id="open_btn_icon">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Three things could be improved to your code works:

1. addEventListener `DOMContentLoaded` to guarantee that when runs `document.querySelectorAll` the DOM is ready;
2. Change from `querySelector`  to `querySelectorAll` tio get all inputs;
3. Rewrite rule that combines to get your inputs;

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  const allInputs = document.querySelectorAll(
    '[name="setting[open_btn_icon]"]'
  );
  allInputs.forEach((input) =>
    input.addEventListener("click", function () {
      alert("Hello World!");
    })
  );
});
```